# Flatten nested List

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Not sure if I'm asking this in the right place or if I'm understanding this correctly. I need change the dictionary so that the occurrence field is added on to the availability key. For example: "Availability.Occurrence": "Daily"

```
 BEFORE
 test_data =  {
              "testDate": "2018-11-19 21:00:00", 
              "testMessage": "This is a test message", 
              "testStatus": "Warning", 
              "Results": [
                         {
                          "Availability": {
                                           "Occurence": "Daily"
                                          }, 
                          "OldestRefreshDate": "2018-11-15 15:40:57 EST", 
                          "TableName": "test"
                         }
                         ], 
              "TaskId": "CheckSourceRefreshDates"
             }
AFTER
     test_data =  {
              "testDate": "2018-11-19 21:00:00", 
              "testMessage": "This is a test message", 
              "testStatus": "Warning", 
              "Results": [
                         {
                          "Availability.Occurrence": "Daily", 
                          "OldestRefreshDate": "2018-11-15 15:40:57 EST", 
                          "TableName": "test"
                         }
                         ], 
              "TaskId": "CheckSourceRefreshDates"
             }
```

I am new to Python just trying to figure all this out. Any help is appreciated.
Heres the function that I tried using, however it only flattens the entire dictionary.

```
def flatten_json(y):
out = {}

def flatten(x, name=''):
    if type(x) is dict:
        for a in x:
            flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
    elif type(x) is list:
        i = 0
        for a in x:
            flatten(a, name + '.')
            i += 1
    else:
        out[name[:-1]] = x

flatten(y)

return out
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, @ShahzadAhmed?

Comment: I tried to create a function that flattens the dictionary . However it just ended up flattening the entire thing. I cant find a way to have it only flatten the Availability dictionary.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then to prove your attempt!

Comment: Welcome @ShahzadAhmed!  It looks like you have JSON data you're trying to transform. Will the key "Occurence" ever reference a value more complex than a simple string? Like a list?

Comment: no the key "Occurrence" will only have a simple string value.

Comment: @ShahzadAhmed, the idea is to pass which argument for name, "Results", "Availability" or "Occurence"?

Comment: I tried Availability but it didn't seem to work. It didn't occur to me to try passing Results or Occurrence.

Comment: I asked because it might change in many aspects the logic of the code.